# org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8443]]

Tags: java, ssl, tomcat7, keystore

I work with apach tomcat 7

I used this kind of command in order to use ssl

```
keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keypass changeit -keyalg RSA

keytool -export -alias tomcat -keypass changeit -file server.cert 

keytool -import -alias tomcat -file %FILE_NAME% -keypass changeit -keystore %JAVA_HOME%/jre/lib/security/cacerts
```

in web.xml of tomcat server

I add this code :

```
 <Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
               maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" 
               keystoreFile="C:\key\server.cert"
               keystorePass="changeit"
               />
```

but when I try to start my server I have this error :

```
SEVERE: Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8443"]
java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to import the **server.cert** file into the **cacerts** file available in the jre lib, you can modify the command as below and try.

*keytool -import -alias tomcat -keystore %JAVA_HOME%/jre/lib/security/cacerts -keypass changeit -file server.cert*

Once given, it will ask for the keystore password and to Re-enter the same. Then give yes to confirm to trust that certificate file.

It works fine for me.

Comment: I think that I should make another format of key in this line       <Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
               maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" 
               keystoreFile="........"
               keystorePass="changeit"
               />